# auto connect bluetooth to last connected device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using bluetooth chat sample and its perfectly fine with pairing the devices and sending text from one device to another but sometimes it disconnects and I would like to reconnect with the last connected device again .How do I achieve this .I have tried auto connect bluetooth from play store but it connects headset and from outside the app not from within.

How do I achieve this from within the App?

Thanks in Advance.

```
E/BluetoothChatService(10175): accept() failed
E/BluetoothChatService(10175): java.io.IOException: Operation Canceled
E/BluetoothChatService(10175):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.acceptNative(Native Method)
E/BluetoothChatService(10175):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.accept(BluetoothSocket.java:311)
E/BluetoothChatService(10175):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:107)
E/BluetoothChatService(10175):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:93)
E/BluetoothChatService(10175):  at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChatService$AcceptThread.run(BluetoothChatService.java:276)




 E/BluetoothChatService(10175): disconnected
 E/BluetoothChatService(10175): java.io.IOException: Software caused connection abort
 E/BluetoothChatService(10175):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readNative(Native Method)
 E/BluetoothChatService(10175):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:333)
 E/BluetoothChatService(10175):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
 E/BluetoothChatService(10175):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
 E/BluetoothChatService(10175):     at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChatService$ConnectedThread.run(BluetoothChatService.java:436)



 E/AndroidRuntime(10175): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1274
 E/AndroidRuntime(10175): java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(10175):   at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChatService.connectionLost(BluetoothChatService.java:242)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10175):   at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChatService.access$6(BluetoothChatService.java:221)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10175):   at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChatService$ConnectedThread.run(BluetoothChatService.java:443)E/BluetoothChat(10175): - ON PAUSE -
```

Comment: I haven't done exactly as your requirement but, you can achieve this by storing your connected device address into shared preferences and then use a broadcast receiver to detect if that address is in the discovery list. If there is then you can connect with it. Follow this link for broasdcast receiver http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: Thank You Milanix for looking into my query.I would like only data to to be sent not audio/headset which is done in auto connect bluetooth app in play store .So How can I achieve that PLease can you provide more clarity on how to achieve the above requirement ,probably a link or working example.Thank You again for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrote this using gEdit since, I don't have eclipse atm. So if there is some coding error please don't hesitate to edit this. For ease of explanation I haven't used SharedPreferences here, if you want to use don't hesitate it.

```
//Assuming that you have device address and is connected
private String partnerDevAdd="00:11:22:AA:BB:CC";
private boolean isConnected=true;

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);

registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for bluetooth related checks
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        //We don't want to reconnect to already connected device
        if(isConnected==false){
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                // Check if the found device is one we had comm with
                if(device.getAddress().equals(partnerDevAdd)==true)
                    connectToExisting(device);
            }
        }

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Check if the connected device is one we had comm with
            if(device.getAddress().equals(partnerDevAdd)==true)
                isConnected=true;
        }else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Check if the connected device is one we had comm with
            if(device.getAddress().equals(partnerDevAdd)==true)
                isConnected=false;
        }
    }
};

private void connectToExisting(BluetoothDevice device){
    new ConnectThread(device);
}
```

ConnectThread is available here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAClient

Comment: Awesome this worked !!.DO you know how to keep connecting bluetooth device till its connected ?? I am using thread.sleep in handler and its working fine but after its connected the loop is running again I would like to end the loop how do I do that .Basically keep running the loop till its connected .Any Ideas ??

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable(){
           public void run() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             while(true)
             {
                try {
     Thread.sleep(5000) ;

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
               //REST OF CODE HERE//    
                   connect();
             }
           }
         }).start();
    }

Comment: How Do I end the above loop ??

Comment: If you take a closer look into the doc it says BluetoothSocket.connect() is a blocking call so ,either it will connect or fail. You can modify that block of code and move return; from try/catch block and move it below manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket) if you want to communicate with only one client at one time. If that's not case, you don't need to stop that thread. And you don't need loop to check that.

Comment: The above code is working without while loop but if I implement while loop it keeps connecting again and again .I would like to end the thread once its connected but every-time I do that the app crashes !! DO you know how I can end the loop ?? I tried many ways Boolean check and stuff but it still crashes..

Comment: can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: I have added it in the question.Thanks again for your Help.Greatly Apprciate !!